# Solr Binary over HTTP

Tags: solr

> "Solr is a standalone enterprise search server with a REST-like API.
>   You put documents in it (called "indexing") via XML, JSON or **binary**
>   over HTTP. You query it via HTTP GET and receive XML, JSON, or binary
>   results."

-- from Solr Website

When it say binary over HTTP? Does it mean, we can bypass the headache of XML/Json parsing, and at the same time save on some bandwidth, right? And Solr will just work as fine as with XML or Json with all its features?

Do you recommend using binary over XML/Json in Solr? Does it have significant performance impact?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The results are written by a [response writer](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/QueryResponseWriter#List_of_Writers_Available). You must be talking about the javabin response writer. [Unfortunately](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/javabin),

> Currently only a **java** library is available to write/read this format .
>   This is the default format used by SolrJ...

I assume you are a .Net guy. If so, you can choose a good JSON library that can deal with JSON in terms of maps and lists, strings and numbers; like Java does. JSON should be easier to parse than (solr's) XML

Comment: Yes, you're right..  I work with .Net. What JSON library do you suggest for this purpose? Currently we're working with XML using Solrnet.

Comment: I never worked with .Net (outside a college project), but noticed you do :-) I suggest you search around: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2682260/net-json-parser-comparison