# C# How to find the distance between two cities

Tags: c#, json, parsing, google-distancematrix-api

I want to know how to find the distance between two cities in c# using Google Maps Distance Matrix API

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=Khouribga&destination=Casablanca
```

But, I don't know how to parse json

I want to display the result in a textbox

Comment: So....what do you expect us to do for you?  Have you even tried researching it first?  Do you need us to google it for you?  Is that what you're asking?

Comment: So your question isn't about the google maps api, but about json. Try using google and searching for something like ".net parsing json".

Comment: So go figure out how to parse json. You obviously haven't made any effort to research this or tried anything yet. Please do so and come back when you have a specific question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [.NET JSON parser comparison](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2682260/net-json-parser-comparison)

Comment: I did try, and I found the something here [Link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13999187/distance-between-addresses) But it didn't work for me

Comment: What does that link have to do with JSON parsing?

Comment: `But it didn't work for me` is not a good description of the problem. How are we supposed to help you if that's all you tell us?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JSON you're getting has everything:

*routes.legs.distance.text*

```
...
   "routes":[
      {
         "bounds":{
            "northeast":{
               "lat":33.5731351,
               "lng":-6.893281399999999
            },
            "southwest":{
               "lat":32.885973,
               "lng":-7.6432116
            }
         },
         "copyrights":"Map data ©2016 Google",
         "legs":[
            {
               "distance":{
                  "text":"126 km",   //here is the distance
                  "value":125977
               }
...
```

Just use a [.net JSON parser](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json) and get this value.

**Sample:**

```
dynamic data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);
string distance = data.routes[0].legs.distance.text;
```

PS: I have not compiled this code sample, just created on assumption. If you get an exception please let me know.